# Single regex for multiples of a character type

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a *single java regex* for asserting that a String (password actually), of any length, has:

- at least 2 lowercase letters
- at least 2 uppercase letters
- at least 2 number characters
- at least 1 character not a letter or number

For use with matches, like:

```
password.matches("some regex");
```

The "important" part here is that there must be *more than one* of a character type. Other questions I've found talk about "at least one", not "at least two" of a character type.

It could be done with multiple matches() calls, but the regex will be externalised as a single String so it needs to be one call to `matches()`.

Comment: i think it has something to do with look aheads, which I'm not familiar with to get right

Comment: I think this cannot be done by a regexp. But is easily done with a few lines of plain old java code.

Comment: I think it can be easily done by using 4 separate regex-es.

Comment: What happens to the regexp when the complexity rules change?

Comment: @msandiford see edit - it would be no problem

Comment: Why does it have to be a regular expression?  Don't get me wrong they're great but I agree with some of the above commenters there are better ways. [Regular Expressions - two problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, you could use a pattern along the lines of the following:

`(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*\\d.*\\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z\\d]).*`

However, for practical uses, I would rather stick with proper programming instead of relying on regular expressions like this one.

Comment: +1 also to make it work with `matches` add `.*` at the end of regex since [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is is zero-width.

Comment: @Pshemo: Of course, you're right. I completely forgot about that behaviour. I've now edited my post. +1

Comment: Will it match password "Aa1Aa1!"?

Comment: @user1883592: Yes, it does match that.

Comment: [Regex planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) I find very useful for testing regular expressions to make sure they work like I think they should.

Comment: @user1883592: You do when using the `String.matcher()` function. It checks for an exact match, meaning that (in terms of speaking) it adds the ^ to the beginning and $ to the end if not added in the string. For example, the expression `foo` (read: `^foo$`) will not match the string `"foobar"`. However, `foo.*` (read: `^foo.*$`) will match `"foobar"`.

Comment: @Bohemian: Did my answer insufficiently help you, seeing as you've unaccepted it?

Comment: @Patrickdev Your answer was fine. I only unaccepted it so the question would get more traffic in the hope that someone would upvote it. Have you upvoted this question? (It's a "hat" thing) I'll re-accept your answer when the question has a score of 1. Thanks for your patience :)